# Two identities involving contour integrals in the presence of a branch point where the integrand explodes, and the Kummer function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic, special-functions, complex

I need to understand how to establish two identities. The first is

$$ \int_{C} z^{-1-q}(1-z)^{-1-\lambda } dz=\frac{2 \pi   \Gamma (q+\lambda +1)}{\Gamma
       (\lambda +1) \Gamma (q+1)}, q\geq 0, \lambda >0$$
where C is a contour $z=1/2+ i t, t \in (-\infty,\infty) $

Mathematica believes this

```
With[{z = l + I t}, 
 Integrate [  
  z^(-q - 1) (1 - z)^(-λ - 1), {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {q > 0, λ > 0, 0 < l < 1}]]
```

When q=0 (RHS is just 2 \pi), this comes from the pole at 0, by using a half circle contour which surrounds it, and blowing it to $\infty$. With q>0, my first idea was to use a rectangle excluding the branch point at 0, but this cannot work since the integrand explodes there

The second identity is a contour integral representation of the HypergeometricU function with powers integrand (unlike the ones given at http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/07/02/ )

$$ \int_{C} e^{-x z} z^{-1-q}(1-z)^{-\lambda } dz=
\frac{2 \pi\ \ e^{-x} x^{q+\lambda} \ U(q+1 , q+\lambda+1,x)}{\Gamma(\lambda ) }, q\geq 0, \lambda >0, x>0$$

Mathematica's `NIntegrate` confirms this

```
cnS = {q -> 5/Pi, \[Lambda] -> 4 Pi, l -> 1/3};
int[x_] := Exp[ -x  z] z^(-q - 1) (1 - z)^(-\[Lambda]) /. cnS;
RBr[x_] := 
  Chop[NIntegrate [
    int[x] /. z -> I t + l /. cnS, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}], 10^(-9)];
R[z_] := 2 Pi  Exp[- z] z^
    n HypergeometricU[q + 1, q + \[Lambda] + 1, z]/Gamma[\[Lambda]];
Print["R Bromwich=", RBr[1], " R exact= ", Chop[R[1] //. cnS // N]]
```

but the hard question for me  is how to prove this by providing the right integration contour.

I also had some intreaguing problems when $\lambda$ is not an integer, but they disappeared on my minimal example above:) I am still wondering though whether `NIntegrate`  could give a wrong answer in  cases when a parameter switches from integer to noninteger.

Comment: What is the Mathematica question here? Whether the second identity holds only for integer values would probably be best disproved by a counter example, i.e. by finding a non-integer value for which it holds. I do not really understand what you are asking in the first part.

Comment: I believe Mathematica is correct with respect to $U(a,b,z)$. Check out the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.4) site, specifically Eq. 13.4.14.

Comment: @MarcoB I would like to know how to prove the first identity. By proof I mean specifying a branch cut, presumably (-\infty, 0 ) union with (1,\infty) and a contour integraI whose limit provides the result, which I do not see yet. This pair changes from example to example, and I could not find  a similar example yet. Once that pair given, the integration and limit are routine exrcises. I am reading simultaneously contour integration examples, but it never hurts to ask. I hope the pair would help proving the second identity, where the exponential was added

Comment: @marcoB  how do I learn to transform latex code so it's displayed as at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/221110/revisions

Comment: @florin The $\LaTeX$ was fine; only, you had it indented by four spaces, so the system Interpreted it as code and displayed it unformatted. I only removed the indenting spaces so the system understood it was LaTeX and formatted it appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Version 12.1 solves the first integral without difficulty.

```
With[{z = 1/2 + I t}, Integrate[z^(-q - 1) (1 - z)^(-λ - 1), {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {q >= 0, λ > 0}]]

(* (2 π Gamma[1 + q + λ])/(Gamma[1 + q] Gamma[1 + λ]) *)
```

I shall give the second integral some thought tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I do believe that this question is of pure mathematics character and does not belong here. Nonetheless, I provide a short answer. A lot of information on special functions can be found in the so called [Bateman Manuscript Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman_Manuscript_Project). There are download links at the bottom of the page. Specifically, you need the volume I, Sec. 6.5
[image]

As I mentioned in the comment above, another comprehensive source on special functions is the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.4) project. The advantage is that they follow modern notations. The disadvantage is that they do not present all derivations.

Comment: "The disadvantage is that (DLMF) do(es) not present all derivations." - They often link to references, which can be accessed by clicking on the circled "i" in the beginning of each section and next to each listed formula.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that is a good point

Comment: One should also probably note at this juncture that there is are connection formulae between the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function $U$ in the OP, and the more conventional Kummer function ${}_1 F_1$, e.g. [this one](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E42), and *Mathematica* might return the ${}_1 F_1$ result which won't work for integer parameters, but will work if $U$ is used instead.

Comment: @yarchik thanks for the reference, I will go dig there! I need however this identity when   a <0 (a=-q in my notation), and I would be more comfortable with a proof using contour integrals, since the sign of a seems crucial, and it seems the proof should exploit that. So, I could use more help :) It's great you answered, I also asked this on the mathematics forum, but there I have no answer yet